# variable of Interface type

Tags: java, interface

I am learning Java, I saw the following description regards to **interface** in a book:

> When a variable is declared to be of an interface type, it simply
>   means that the object is expected to have implemented that interface.

**What does it mean?** If I define an **interface**:

```
public interface Myinterface{

   void method_one(); 
   int method_two();
}
```

Then, I declare a **variable** to be of an interface type for example:

```
Myinterface foo = new Myinterface();
```

- How the interface get implemented??
- Under what circumstance I should define a interface type variable?

I completely get confused by the book's description...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You cannot instantiate an interface, i.e. you cannot do

```
MyInterface foo = new MyInterface(); // Compile-time error.
```

What you can do is instantiate a class that implements the interface. That is, given a class `MyClass`

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
  // ...

  @Override
  void method_one() {
    // ...
  }
  @Override
  int method_two() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

you can instantiate it and place a reference to it in your variable like this:

```
MyInterface foo = new MyClass();
```

If you had another class implementing `MyInterface`

```
class MyClass2 implements MyInterface {
  // ...
}
```

you can also substitute a reference to this class's instance under your variable:

```
MyInterface foo = new MyClass2();
```

This is where the power of interfaces lies: they define **types**, not a particular **implementation** and let you refer to any implementation of a given type.

It is a very good programming practice to make classes implement interfaces and to use these to refer to instances of these classes. This practice facilitates a great deal of flexibility and reuse.

Therefore, you should use interface type arguments and variables whenever it is conceivable that different implementations may be passed into the method you're implementing. For example, if you're working with a `HashSet<T>` instance, you should use a variable of type `Set<T>` to refer to it (class `HashSet<T>` implements interface `Set<T>`).

Answer (score 5):

You cannot instantiate an interface. But you may type your variable with the interface name:

```
Myinterface foo = new MyObject();
```

Assuming `MyObject` implements `MyInterface`.

It may be useful when acquiring objects from an external source, for instance.
In such a case, you don't know (and don't care) about the real type of the object.

You only need to know and ensure it implements some interface, so you can call interface methods on the object.

Assuming you have the following variable:

```
Myinterface foo;
```

And two classes (`Foo` and `Bar`), both implementing `MyInterface`.
You will then be able to assign the `foo` variables with instances of both `Foo` and `Bar`.

The same applies to methods arguments, of course.

Comment: Thank you,Can you also answer my 2nd question, under what circumstance I should do this thing? Why do it like this? What is the benefit?

Comment: Thank you, both you and Adam give me a very clear explanation:)

Answer (score 1):

You don't instantiate an interface. You create classes that *implement* the interface, instantiate those, but reference the interface (as opposed to the implementing class).

This allows your code to remain implementation-neutral, similar to using a `List` reference, but an `ArrayList` implementation.

When combined with dependency injection it makes testing and extensibility much easier, too.